# Get DataGridView cell value in nested For Loops

Tags: .net, vb.net, validation, datagridview

I've got some data displayed on a `DataGridView`, and in my `btnSave_Click`event, I'm calling a subroutine to validate the data in the grid before saving it into my database.

The way I'm doing it is by using a loop for each row and inside that loop using another for loop, for each column.

I need to then compare each char in the cell value that it's validating (row dr, cell dc). However, I cannot work out the way to use the row/column co-ordinates to get the value in the cell.

It's a little hard to explain what I mean, but in this code I have the `For Loops` set up on the first 2 lines, then on the third line, notice `If IsDBNull(dc.TextInCell)` - TextInCell is what I need to replace.

In Row; dr and Column; dc, I need to then validate the value stored in that cell...

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgvImport.Rows
   For Each dc As DataGridViewColumn In dgvImport.Columns
     If dc.HeaderText = "Product Code" Then
       If IsDBNull(dc.TextInCell) = True Or dc.TextInCell = Nothing Or dc.TextInCell = "" Then
          Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
          MsgBox("Import failed. One or more required fields were not entered", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
          Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each c As Char In dc.TextInCell
         If Not Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) Then
          If Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) Then
           If c <> "&" AndAlso c <> "-" AndAlso c <> "(" AndAlso c <> ")" Then
             Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
             MsgBox("Import failed. One or more cells contains an invalid character", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
             Exit Sub
           End If
          End If
         End If
Next
```

How do I get the cell value into a variable from here to send it through the validation?

Comment: There are events which will allow you to validate as you go so you can tell the user they have an error *when they make it* rather than "there is an error somewhere on this page".  CellValidating is one, CellLeave is also a possibility

Comment: @Plutonix Not sure that's possible here. This is data that has been selected from an Excel spreadsheet and the `DataSource` is the `DataTable` I filled after selecting it

Comment: In that case, I would definitely not loop thru the DGV, but the DataTable rows.  You could add a column which indicates which ones pass and which ones fail and provide some visual cue

Comment: @Plutonix The issue with that being that I can't then use the column caption to decide what validation is required. Different users will have different column headers in their spreadsheets (But always in the same order), so doing it using the DGV means I can set the index header and that way not worry what the user called it in the spreadsheet.

Comment: If you know the order you can use that to trigger this or that validation.  You could also probably dump most or all that code in place of a RegEx.  You'd probably have to call on those again if they edit the bad data into good so you can check that it is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will (almost) always be faster to iterate the rows in the datatable than to root thru the control.  There is also at least one inefficiency in your code:

```
For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgvImport.Rows
    For Each dc As DataGridViewColumn In dgvImport.Columns
        If dc.HeaderText = "Product Code" Then
```

You dont need to find the target column for each row - it will be at the same index for each row.

I dont know what the expected pattern is for these, but if there is a defined  pattern like "N-LLL-AAA-NLN" (e.g: `9-WDM-6K6-6ZC`) you might want to look into **[RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)** for comprehensive pattern testing.  For instance your code is basically just testing for a limited set of special characters *anywhere* in the string; if there is a `(` shouldn't it be before any `)`?

You will surely need to fiddle with the actual validation code, but this is many times faster:

```
'... code to fill the DT
' add a column to track if the row is valid
dtSample.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("IsValid", GetType(Boolean)))

Dim specialChars = "&-()"
Dim txt As String = ""
Dim bValid As Boolean
Dim prodIndex As Int32

' index of the target column using the column name
prodIndex = dtSample.Columns.IndexOf("ProductCode")  

For Each dr As DataRow In dtProduct.Rows
    ' get the text
    txt = dr.Field(Of String)(prodIndex)

    ' first check for nothing from DBNull
    bValid = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt) = False
    ' if there is text data, check the content
    If bValid Then
        ' each char must be letter, digit or authorized special char
        For n As Int32 = 0 To txt.Length - 1
            If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(txt(n)) = False AndAlso
                        specialChars.Contains(txt(n)) = False Then
                bValid = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ' unabiguously set the column for each row
    dr("IsValid") = bValid
Next

dgv1.DataSource = dtSample
' hide our scratch column
dgv1.Columns("IsValid").Visible = False
```

Results:

[image]

Not shown is 2-3 lines in the `RowPrePaint` event to color the rows where `IsValid` is false.  More importantly, it is fast: **125 milliseconds** to process 75,000 rows; digging thru the DGV and finding the same column over and over takes 7-8 secs.

Even without RegEx, you can test for special characters at specific locations (assuming a fixed pattern).  For instance, to test `"A-78*X(2012)"`:

```
bValid = pcode(1) = "-"c AndAlso
         pcode(4) = "*"c AndAlso
         pcode(6) = "("c AndAlso
         pcode(11) = ")"c
```

You could also split the string by those characters in order to test that `parts(3)` is a value between 2010 and 2015 or whatever, if you wanted to perform that level of testing. The more of that you do, the more useful RegEX would be.

Comment: I just corrected a tiny bit of logic in this. The way it was, whenever `bValid` was `False`, it was setting the first row of the grid to show as false, even if it was row 4, for example. Otherwise it's fine