# Looping through a specific dataset column to check if it contains a certain value

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, rows

I load a datagridview and am trying to find a quick way of looping through a certain column, given column name....

This is how my datagridview is loaded....

```
ad = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
ad.Fill(ds, "Fields")
dgvFields.DataSource = ds.Tables("Fields")

dgvFields.ReadOnly = True
dgvFields.RowHeadersVisible = False

dgvFields.Columns(0).Width = 156
dgvFields.Columns(1).Width = 156
dgvFields.Columns(2).Width = 156
dgvFields.Columns(3).Width = 157
```

'Now I want to be able to loop through dgvfields.columns(3) or column name "Field1a" and check if dgvfields.rows="ValueA"

something along the lines...

```
   For Each row As DataRow In dgvFields.Columns(5)
       if dgvfields.rows.value="ValueA" then
          'do something
       End if

   Next
```

Comment: Scan the datatable not the control - the snippet is mixing and matching DT and DGV elements.  see [Get DataGridView cell value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552536/get-datagridview-cell-value-in-nested-for-loops/40556752#40556752)  for a vb, loop version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the type you are looking at for your row... `DataRow` is for a `DataTable` ***not*** a `DataGridViewRow`... I would recommend using the index...

**Note:** this can be done many way's.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvFields.Rows.Count - 1
       If dgvfields.Rows(i).Cells("THE COLUMN NAME").Value="ValueA" Then
          'do something
       End if    
Next
```

Comment: @ thank you, now If i wanted to change the color of a particular row where the value is what I'm looking for?
dgvfields.rows(i).defaultcellstyle.backColor = color.blue doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: It does work, are you doing this on the load event,  if so it will not work. `dgvfields.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = YOURCOLOR` will work but cant be done on the load because it blocks the cell from being changed. Look into [**RowPostPaint**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) which there you can change the color if you would like, this occurs after the DataGridView messages are pumped.

Comment: well I'm calling a function from LOAD to populate the grid

Comment: That's fine, then do it on the event I said in my last comment...as if doing it from a load(instantiation) it's blocking the changing of the colors... Also if I answered your original question please accept the answer. On another note, please do not ask other questions within the comments its not polite and no one else see's it anyways unless they read the comments; create another question.